# Javascript : onHashchange Test

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, hashchange

I'm trying to check if the browser supports `onHashChange` or not to hide some code from it if not, in this way:

```
if(window.onhashchange){
    ...code...
} else {
   ...other code...
}
```

I tried this too:

```
if(typeof window.onhashchange === "function"){
    alert("Supports");  
} else {
    alert("Doesn't Supports");  
}
```

As described on **[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html)** this should work but if I do an `alert` for example in `true state` in `Safari` than alerts me but Safari is not supporting `onHashChange` :S

What's the problem with it? If I'm not on the right way how should I check it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can detect this event by using the `in` operator:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
  //...
}
```

See also:

- [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onhashchange#Example) - MDC
- [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/)
- [Emulating `onhashchange` without setInterval](http://ajaxian.com/archives/emulating-onhashchange-without-setinterval)

Answer (score 6):

Be warned that you're better off using feature detection rather than existence inference (such as "onhashchange" in window).

@xkit explained to me a good feature test to work around the fact that although IE7 doesn't support onhashchange it would still return true for existence inference such as if("onhashchange" in window){/*code*/} when using IE7 Standard Document Mode in IE8.

What @xkit suggested was setting a flag (such as var isSet = true;) within a handler function for the onhashchange event. Then changing window.location.hash using JavaScript and see if the flag was set.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the version of Safari that you're using has added support for the `onhashchange` event since the time that that Quirksmode article was written.  Tests should still be valid; try it in other browsers you know not to support the event.

Edit: also, you should use the method described by @CMS instead, as the event will not contain a function by default; thus both of those tests will fail.

Answer (score 1):

if (window.onhashchange !== undefined) alert('Supports onhashchange');