# Is using 'eventhandler' in window a safe method of determining if window supports a given event handler?

Tags: javascript, events, window, handler, detect

All credit goes to:

http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/#add-and-remove-hashchange

For this method, but we were wondering if doing the following:

```
if('onhashchange' in window){
    console.log('yep, window supports onhashchange');
}
else{
    console.log('nope, window does not support onhashchange');
}
```

Is a safe method of determining if the window object supports the onhashchange event handler?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript : onHashchange Test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030390/javascript-onhashchange-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is generally not a safe test, although it may be OK for this particular event since it is relatively new. There is no guarantee about how host objects (such as `window`) will respond to the `in` operator and some browsers, including old versions Firefox, do not return `true` for event handler properties. The following article has details:

http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/

It seems [Firefox added support for detecting event support using the `in` operator in version 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_handlers) while `onhashchange` was [added in 3.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange), so unless there was special behaviour for `onhashchange`, your test will give false negatives in Firefox 3.6 - 8.0.

**UPDATE**

I've now tested in Firefox 3.6 and it seems `onhashchange` is a special case because your test works: `'onhashchange' in window` returns true, while `'onload' in window`, for example, does not. It looks like your test may be OK, although I would still recommend testing all your target browsers carefully.

Comment: we ended up using the method in the article mentioned. works great across a wide array of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It checks if key `'onhashchange'` present in object `window` and return boolean value. There is no unsafe usage.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```
if (window.onhashchange) ...
```

Comment: That's worse. The idea is to check whether the event is supported by the browser, not whether a handler has been set.

Comment: If some other script adds `window.onhashchange=function(){}` before you do this check, it will be invalid.

Comment: ok, I agree, but is it not better then `if('onhashchange' in window)` which is not standard syntax AFAIK...

Comment: No, the `in` operator is standard syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in